# Problems with angular.js routing and maps

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem that when i using a Routing, I don't understand why but maps duplicate, instead one map i have two.

Html file:

```
<div id="contacts" ng-controller="twoCtrl">
    <section class="map-wrapper">
        <div class="maps" id="mapOne"></div>
        <div class="maps" id="mapTwo"></div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Css :
    section.map-wrapper {
        margin-top: 30px;
        position: relative;
        height: 310px;
        width: 100%;
    }

```
section.map-wrapper .maps {
    position: absolute;
    height: auto;
    height: 310px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .5s;
}

section.map-wrapper .maps.active {
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

js

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl : "main.html",
        controller: 'oneCtrl'
    })
    .when("/contacts", {
        templateUrl : "pages/contacts.html",
        controller: 'twoCtrl'
    })
});
app.controller('twoCtrl',function($scope){
    $(function() {
        //maps' active classes
            maps();
            function maps() {
                $(".load-block:first").addClass('active');
                $(".maps:first").addClass('active');
                $(".office-block[id='office']").addClass("active");
                $("#office").click(function() {
                    $(".office-block[id='branch']").removeClass("active");
                    $(".office-block[id='office']").addClass("active");
                    $(".maps").removeClass("active");
                    $("#mapOne").addClass("active");
                });

                $("#branch").click(function() {
                    $(".office-block[id='office']").removeClass("active");
                    $(".office-block[id='branch']").addClass("active");
                    $(".maps").removeClass("active");
                    $("#mapTwo").addClass("active");
                });
            };

         //map
    ymaps.ready(init);
        var myMap1,
            myMap2,
            myPlacemark,
            myPlacemark2

        function init(){ 
            myMap1 = new ymaps.Map("mapOne", {
                center: [50.0094033, 36.2345667],
                zoom: 16,
                controls: []
            }); 

            myMap2 = new ymaps.Map("mapTwo", {
                center: [49.7118034, 37.6141396],
                zoom: 16,
                controls: []
            }); 

            myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([50.0094033, 36.2345667], {
                hintContent: 'Охрана и технологии',
                balloonContent: 'г. Харьков, ул. Данилевского, 12 офис 22'
            }, {
                iconLayout: 'default#image',
                iconImageHref: 'includes/icons/map-mark.png',
                iconImageSize: [35, 35]
            });

            myPlacemark2 = new ymaps.Placemark([49.7118034, 37.6141396], {
                hintContent: 'Охрана и технологии',
                balloonContent: 'г.Купянск, пл.Ленина, оф.34'
            }, {
                iconLayout: 'default#image',
                iconImageHref: 'includes/icons/map-mark.png',
                iconImageSize: [35, 35]
            });

            myMap1.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);
            myMap2.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark2);
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove ng-controller="twoCtrl" from your html code

```
<div id="contacts" ng-controller="twoCtrl">
```

You have already assigned it in your $routeConfig

Comment: thanks a lot it work now :) but i really don't understand why, if I'm not mistaken if you have some script on page which you want to see, using routing you can't add this script to your main js file you have to add this to angular file and set ng-controller

Comment: Yeah, there are so many approaches you can use. Here you are  assigning your angular main module in app. Then you write some configuration for your app. In this configuration you are binding a "Controller & Template" for a specific route. when the view is rendering on that specific route url, then it is automatically calling that attached controller for that route url. If you write ng-controller="someCtrl" on view 
in this situation, then it will be called twice. I think you have understand